# Laravel Dusk (TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform)

Tags: php, laravel

**Steps to reproduce:**

Installed as written here `https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#installation`

**1) composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^1.0**

**2) app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider;

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->environment('local', 'testing')) {
        $this->app->register(DuskServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

**3) php artisan dusk:install**

**4) php artisan dusk**

Got the message on my console "TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform." And no test is running

**My Configuration is as follows:**

- Windows 10 64bit
- WampServer 3.1.0
- Apache 2.4.27
- PHP 7.0.23
- Laravel Framework version 5.3.31
- composer require laravel/passport=~1.0
- console cmder emulator
- chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

> TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

Is an accurate statement, its not supported - it should not affect the running of dusk.  The current solution is to ignore it!

see [here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/276) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/pull/226)